# application idle

Tags: wpf

How do I make my `WPF` application go idle when a particular event fires?

```
void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock) {
            //make application idle
        }
        else if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock) {
            //run the app again
        }
    }
```

I have my code like this, when ever user locks the Windows, if condition gets fired and when he unlocks it else gets fired.

Can some one suggest me code for making the app idle and running it again?

Comment: What do you mean by "making the app idle"? Your app *is* idle whenever it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make an application "idle" in Windows.  You can make the application threads suspended using the [Thread.Suspend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx) method but you need at least one of the threads (i.e. the main thread) running in order for the application to resume the other threads.

Suspending and resuming threads is **not** a good idea though. It would be a much better solution to intelligently pause and resume the tasks that an application is performing.  For example, if your application is playing a video, you should find a clean way to pause the video control and resume the video when it needs to.  Suspending and resuming threads would likely create unexpected behavior and a bad user experience.